# How do you specify a str.format() style inside a logging Handler?

Tags: python, logging, string-formatting

In my code I am writing dict-objects on every `LogRecord`. One of the keys are called `my_msg` and I want to create a `StreamHandler` that just prints out the time and the value of the `my_msg` key.
I have tried the following but I get an error message: `AttributeError: type object 'LogRecord' has no attribute 'levelname'`

```
streamformatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='{}:\t{}'.format(logging.LogRecord.levelname, logging.LogRecord.message.get('my_msg'), datefmt='%H:%M:%S', style='{')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass *just the template* to the `Formatter()` class. The template will then be used *later on* to format your message. You also need to use named slots:

```
streamformatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='{levelname}:\t{my_msg}', datefmt='%H:%M:%S', style='{')
```

You don't call `.format()` on it when creating the `Formatter()` object; at that moment there is no log message yet and no level to be filled in.

See the [logrecord attributes section](http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) for what names are available by default; any `%`-style formatting in the second column of the table should be translated to new-style formats instead:

- `%(asctime)s` becomes `{asctime}` or `{asctime!s}`
- `%(created)f` becomes `{created:f}`
- `%(lineno)d` becomes `{lineno:d}`.

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It is happening to me often in these noob days that I am calling stuff before it is needed.. The question was two-fold though. Second part of the question was on how I could access  the value of a key inside the dictionary which each of logrecords is an instance of?

Comment: You need to be more explicit there; are you creating custom `LogRecord` instances with extra attributes? If so, use the syntax above (`my_msg` is such an attribute). Are you passing in arguments to a `.log()` or `.info()` or related call? Then those are interpolated into the first argument of the call and all you need to do in the `LogRecord` format is include `msg`.